# Running multipile macros in the same sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to run a macro that will fill in the date and time when something has been updated, but I need to have it happen twice in the same row.

I have it set up to fill in column B+C when initials are entered in column A, but I would like to to run when someone enters another value in column N

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In Inte
        If r.Value > 0 Then
           r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
           r.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yy"
           r.Offset(0, 2).Value = Time
           r.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
        Else
           r.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
           r.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Use multiple checks in Inte or use a select case/IF based on the target.column and/or target.row values

Comment: @Joseph_Schleiss: I see you're new. Please be courteous and "Accept" the answer if you think it appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to test what the Address/location of the Target range is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 1 ' "A"

            Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
            Set A = Range("A:A")
            Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
            If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            For Each r In Inte
                If r.Value > 0 Then
                   r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
                   r.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yy"
                   r.Offset(0, 2).Value = Time
                   r.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
                Else
                   r.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
                   r.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
                End If
            Next r

        Case 14 ' "N"
                ' Do something else

    End Select

    Application.EnableEvents = True ' <-- Don't forget to turn this back on!

End Sub
```

Further, since such an approach can get unwieldy, it's often a good idea to break down your methods. (Smaller methods are almost always better.)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 1, ' "A"
            Call AddDatesAfterInitialsEntered(Target)

        Case 14 ' "N"
            ' Do something else

    End Select

    Application.EnableEvents = True ' <-- Don't forget to turn this back on!

End Sub

Private Sub AddDatesAfterInitialsEntered(Target As Range)

    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In Inte
        If r.Value > 0 Then
           r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
           r.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yy"
           r.Offset(0, 2).Value = Time
           r.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
        Else
           r.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
           r.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: I was just looking through some older questions and noticed this answer - I think your `Case 2, 3 ' "A" or "B"` should be `Case 1 ' "A"` because column A and B are columns 1 and 2, not 2 and 3, and the OP was testing for changes in column A, not column A and B.  The way the code is currently set up, a change in column A will not trigger any calculations.   Also `Target.Column` just returns the column of the **first** cell in `Target`, so testing should probably be done by an `If Not Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing`.

Comment: True that. I updated the case statement. I did not update for the Intersect. It's a valid point, of course. I'll trust that your comment is enough to steer people in the right direction.

Comment: As long as the clean-up routines don't delete the comment, it should be fine.